# Swift iOS: Share text from live activity

Tags: ios, swift

I show some text in dynamic island and want to add a share button. How can I achieve this in a LiveActivityIntent? Or is it possible to write it to the clipboard?

LiveActivity

```
...
DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
    Button(intent: ShareIntent()) {
    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
    }
}
...
```

ShareIntent

```
struct ShareIntent:LiveActivityIntent{
    init() {}

    static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Live activity"
    static var isDiscoverable: Bool = false

    func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
        print("share content")

        // Write to clipboard
        UIPasteboard.general.string = "test" // This leads to error Pasteboard com.apple.UIKit.pboard.general is not available at this time
        return .result()
    }
}
```